# Want to change TextView on button click from soft keyboard

Tags: android

I have an alertDialog and when the user hits the Done button on soft keyboard I want to use the setText() method to change the textView in the listView. I can use setText() method seemingly anywhere but in the Done button on click method, although calling a toast from Done button on click works. The faulty code is in the ArrayAdapter class. This is all my code and the log cat messages when I hit the Done button.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<String> Chores = new ArrayList<>();
        Chores.add("");
        //final String[] Chores = {"", "", ""};
        final ListAdapter MyAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Chores);
        ListView listViewObject = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.customListView_ID);
        listViewObject.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

        listViewObject.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    String ChoreString = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));




                }
            }

        );
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ID);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Chores.add("");
                ((ArrayAdapter)MyAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });




    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
 import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custon_listview_row, parent, false);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_ID);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ID);
        final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
        final AlertDialog OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();







        //makes textView clickable
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //what happens when textView is clicked
                //final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                // put aler dialog box logic here
                OptionDialog.setTitle("Enter new chore");
                OptionDialog.setView(input);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                //checks if "Done" button on soft keyboard is clicked
                input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                            //what happens when "Done" is clicked

                            //textView wont change to string hello
                            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // your stuff to update the UI
                                    textView.setText("hello");
                                }
                            });





                            //this toast works
                           // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                            //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            OptionDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });



                OptionDialog.show();
            }
        });


        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);

        return customView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.emilythacker.chorelist.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/customListView_ID"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Add Chore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_ID" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_listview_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_ID"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <TextView
        android:text="Click here to add chore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/textView_ID"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton_ID"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

log cat messages

```
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{e0eeb0a token=android.os.BinderProxy@76a5b43
```

Comment: Have you tried not using Runnable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try postDelayed() instead of post() like below.

```
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your stuff to update the UI
            textView.setText("hello");
        }
    },200);
```

I hope it will work.